# Hook/Overlay a DirectX game?

Tags: c#, directx, hook, overlay

Can anyone tell me how to hook/overlay a DirectX game in C#?

I've tried getting a fullscreen C# window to overlap a game, however it wont.
After researching a little, I found out that I need to hook the game and then display the C# window.

Can anyone explain how I would do this?
Would I be able to display a C# form over a DirectX game?

Comment: Anyone? If anyone's seen the Steam or xFire overlay, I want it like that. The users are able to surf the net while playing games, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(disclosure: I work for this company)

You can try our [Deviare API](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/), it has functionality to hook COM objects from C#.
It's a set of COM objects that can be used from any programming language (supporting COM). An article with source code showing how to capture video and add an overlay is available: [instrumenting Direct3D applications to capture video and calculate FPS](http://blog.nektra.com/main/2013/07/23/instrumenting-direct3d-applications-to-capture-video-and-calculate-frames-per-second/)

[COM Spy Console](http://www.nektra.com/products/com-spy-console) and [Direct Sound Capture](http://blog.nektra.com/main/2009/02/24/directsound-capture-using-deviare/) are two examples that implements a console to hook COM objects like DirectX.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I've applied for it. Could you explain how I could get the Deviare API to hook a directx game, and display something? Thanks again.

Comment: You can ask questions in the related forums there. My recommendation is using the articles as a starting point.

Comment: That does not solve the problem for others. Please describe what the solution is.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen source code for adding an overlay and capturing video using Deviare is available at: https://github.com/nektra/AVRecorderTool

Answer (score 16):

You can try [my example on hooking the Direct3D 9 API using C#](http://spazzarama.com/2010/03/29/screen-capture-with-direct3d-api-hooks/). This utilizes EasyHook an open source .NET assembly that allows you to install hooks from managed code into unmanaged functions.

SlimDX is also used - this is an open source managed wrapper around the Direct3D libraries.

The tricky part of the hooking is determining the addresses of a COM objects' virtual functions. This is done in the above example using a small C++ helper DLL that finds the addresses from the VTable. [Update: there is a comment posted that show's how to get the function pointers from the VTable in C# also - given a IntPtr to the com object]

The example hooks the EndScene method of an IDirect3DDevice9, which is also where you would want to draw any overlays. As to displaying a form in the overlay I'm not so sure that will be so easy - I mean you can render the image easily enough, but you will have to capture inputs and manually respond/pass-thru the events to the form in question appropriately. Good luck!

Comment: Here's an updated version that has a very simple Overlay example - also 100% C#: [Direct3D 9,10 overlay](http://spazzarama.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/c-screen-capture-and-overlays-for-direct3d-9-10-and-11-using-api-hooks/)

Comment: link is down unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have direct DirectX Access from C# this may be tricky.

From my limited understanding of the concept:

DirectX Hooks consist of attaching to a DirectX Context and manipulating it, this may/may not require messing with another program's memory, something that's best suited to C/C++

I may be wrong though, however this is an advanced topic and my gut tells me you may have issues under .NET

Comment: How about doing the hooking with C++, and then running the C# Program from within the hook? Wouldn't that make the C# program show, or doesn't it work like that?

Comment: No, you can't show a C# program within unmanaged C++ like that. One common suggestion is to use C++/CLI for a managed/unmanaged C++ wrapper half-interfacing with DirectX but also half of a "managed" library that C# can directly call. But it looks ugly. Spazzarrama (Justin S. ^)'s example of hooking and overlaying works perfectly and was an invaluable resource.