# c# text/winForm overlay video games like xfire,PIX,steam,fraps etc

Tags: c#, c++, directx, overlay

I know there is plenty of post about this topic , however I've been looking for a solution to this for months. I checked about 300 posts on google about this. The only good thing I found was a c++ program that was drawing a colored rectangle over League's window. I am not very familiar with directx. My program is in c# and I would to write text or if possible make a winForm visible over a full screen video game.

I tried every single sample found on forums but 50% of them are old and links aren't working anymore.

Hope you guys can help me.

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649702/c-sharp-hook-overlay-a-directx-game Maybe this?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect directx games by looking which dlls are importing.there is certain dlls like http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/d3dx_dlls.html.