# Freeze screen during capture in c#

Tags: c#

I want to freeze my screen when i press printscreen (to capture region)
Example:
When im watching a movie or playing a game and i press the Print screen it freeze the current position.
Is this possible?

Comment: There's no such thing as "freeze the screen". You can, however, create a fullscreen window and display the screen capture, which is what most screen capturing software do.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi just like pressing the Pause button, stop all moving content ..

Comment: See Cody Gray's answer here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049122/capture-the-screen-shot-using-net

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you want to capture an overlay. Maybe this post will be useful for you: [Hook/Overlay a DirectX game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649702/hook-overlay-a-directx-game)